# My script stops after a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

My script is acting strange. After a foreach loop, the script stops. I don't have any error, any warning or notice from Apache.
This is the code:

```
foreach($clientFact as $line)
{
    $cliTemp1[] = $line["idcliente"];
    echo "qwerty";
}
echo "123";
```

If I add an "echo(qwerty")" inside the loop, it will show the "qwerty" but, right after the end of the loop it will not do anything.

Am I missing something?!

Thanks

Comment: Looks ok... could it be running out of memory?

Comment: i think this line is giving you problem. $cliTemp1[] = $line["idcliente"];

Please check $cliTemp1[], provide array index in it.

Comment: have you tried putting var_dump($clientFact); exit; before the loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apache wouldnt return an error as its a PHP error. Adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

on the top of your page is a very good idea so you can see every error that happens. It could also be your error handler that is not displaying the error and just ending the script.

If it is a problem with your error handler, add

```
restore_error_handler();
```

before the error_reporting function

Edit: read your comment about the array index. It definately sounds like a memory limit being reached in PHP if it stops at a specific index every time.

You could use:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');
```

to change your memory limit to 100megs. Not recommended but if it works, its a problem with not enough memory. Try to refactor your program so it uses less memory

Comment: Sounds like changing the memory limit *identified* your problem. Since you said in a comment "tomorrow will be more, for sure", I think you have to do something else to *solve* your problem. You should probably figure out a way to do what you need to do without loading the entire $cliTemp1 array all at once.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax above looks fine, so as a complete shot in the dark here - how big is the `$clientFact` array? Is it possible that the `$cliTemp1` array is getting so large it's tripping a memory limit?

Maybe rather than echoing "qwerty", echo out the contents of `$line["idcliente"]` on each iteration to be sure you're successfully getting through all elements in `$clientFact`.

Comment: instead of qwerty I just added a counter inside the loop and it stops always in the iteration number 11815.
My array has 109247 elements, today. Tomorrow will be more, for sure.

Comment: OK, sounds like the OOM problem hit you. Ozzy's suggestion is right

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you're dying on an error inside the loop because one of your `$line`s isn't an array like you expect, and the error is being hidden.  Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` before the loop, and possibly `ini_set('display_errors', true)`.

Comment: As I said earlier, Apache do not return any error, warning or notice.

Comment: Yeeaaah.... I'm saying that's likely to be because they're getting suppressed.  I don't know anything about your php.ini settings, though, so it's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: You have to configure php too to show all errors. By default they are not visible.